# How to keep leading zero on CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android, string, time, countdowntimer

I am using a `CountDownTimer` to display time remaining.

The math is correct but it's removing the leading zero.

it would give me `1:9` instead of `01:09`.

Here is my code:

```
final TextView mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         long secondsUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
         long minutes = secondsUntilFinished / 60;
         long seconds = secondsUntilFinished % 60;
         String time = String.format("%d:%d", minutes, seconds);
         mTextField.setText(time);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

I get an compiler warning on `String.format("%d:%d", minutes, seconds);` but I am not sure if it has something to do with it:

> Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use
>   String.format(Locale, ...) instead

Comment: read String.format documentation.

Comment: as for the warning, it is just indicating that when your app will run on a device with different characters for the numbers, it may look weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
```

About your warning, it is to let you avoid unexpected issues.

For example, if you use %d without setting locale to the US on an arabic phone, it will display arabic digits.
So, having this warning helps you to remember about this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks this works, do you know how stop that warning

Comment: String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

but use it only if you want to display in the user locale (for example, use .(point) in english and ,(coma) in french for floating numbers).

But if you want to have a result planned in advanced, prefer to set the Locale in which you want to display the result :

String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

Comment: Thanks I changed as suggested (Locale.US) but I get different warning now `Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs`

Comment: This is only due to Eclipse. Clean your project :-) (For that, in Eclipse, click on Project, then Clean, then select at least the project in which you have your warning)